# Find two functions given properties of their limits

Tags: calculus, limits

I've been stuck on a seemingly simple problem regarding limit properties of two functions:

Find two functions, f(x) and g(x), given the following properties:

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 7} f(x)=0$$

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 7} g(x)=0$$

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 7} \frac{[g(x)]^2}{f(x)}=2$$

I'm very curious as to how solve problems of this type in general. I use statistics and linear algebra everyday in my work, but I haven't solved calculus problems of this type since I was in school.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example
$$f(x)=(x-7)^2\quad;\quad g(x)=\sqrt2(x-7)$$

Comment: Is there a method to solve problems of this type? I'm not sure why I struggled with this problem, as it should be relatively simple.

Comment: Do you want to know how I thought?: take a function that has the limit $0$ at $7$ for example $g(x)=\ln(8-x)$ and let $f(x)=\frac1{ 2}g^2(x)$ and you have another example;-)

Comment: Nice picks! (My day has been very very slow!)